# ReactJS: How to add Component into Dom Element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React basic.
I need to append a component to the DOM after the DOM is rendered, on a event hover.

```
function Movie() {
const elementContext = useContext(ElementProvider);

const handleHover = (e) => {
    const elementWrapper = elementContext.current;
    const top = e.pageX;
    const left = e.pageY;
    
    elementWrapper.appendChild(<HoverScaleMovie top={top} left={left} />)
};
    return (...)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In react normally you do this in a different way. You define the element in the return statement and control it via the state.

```
function Movie() {
    const elementContext = useContext(ElementProvider);
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false)
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({
       top: 0, 
       left: 0,
    })
    const handleHover = (e) => {
       const elementWrapper = elementContext.current;
       const top = e.pageX;
       const left = e.pageY;
       setIsHovered(true); 
       setPosition({
          top: top, 
          left: left
       })
    };
    return ({isHovered && <HoverScaleMovie top={position.top} left={position.left} />})
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want Component HoverScaleMovie is child const elementWrapper

Comment: Then go to the elementWrapper and add the HoverScaleMovie as a child of elementWrapper in the return statement with the condition

Comment: How to add Component HoverScaleMovie into elementWrapper when elementWrapper is a tag div element

Comment: Can you also post your code in the return statement?